# clear function in excel does not work

Tags: excel

i know  that The Excel CLEAN function removes all non-printable characters from a supplied text string.for instance let us consider following  command in excel

```
=CHAR(127)& "10"
```

result is

[image]

it is located at cell at A1,but command

```
=CLEAN(A1)
```

will leave result same,so what is  problem? why it does not work

Comment: maybe you can use =SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(127),”"), instead?

Comment: yes  i know this i have used  just it was curious

Answer (score 0):

[from Microsoft Office Support: CLEAN Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CLEAN-function-26F3D7C5-475F-4A9C-90E5-4B8BA987BA41)

The CLEAN function was designed to remove the first 32 nonprinting characters in the 7-bit ASCII code (values 0 through 31) from text. In the Unicode character set, there are additional nonprinting characters (values 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, and 157). By itself, the CLEAN function does not remove these additional nonprinting characters

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that can remove those character on selection range

```
Sub Remove_Invisible_Character()
'Remove spaces and nonprinting characters from text

'9,13,28,29,30,31,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,
'138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,
'153,154,155,156,157,158,159,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,
'1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,6155,6156,6157,6158,8203,8204,
'8205,8206,8207,8233,8234,8235,8236,8237,8238,8289,8290,8291,8292,
'8298,8299,8300,8301,8302,8303,64976,64977,64978,64979,64980,64981,
'64982,64983,64984,64985,64986,64987,64988,64989,64990,64991,64992,
'64993,64994,64995,64996,64997,64998,64999,65000,65001,65002,65003,
'65004,65005,65006,65007,65060,65061,65062,65063,65064,65065,65066,
'65067,65068,65069,65070,65071,65279


Dim C, nArrSearch As Variant
Dim nRng As Range
Dim firstAddress, nMsg, nChar As String
Dim bRemoved As Boolean
Dim N As Single
Dim nSearchStr As Variant

nChar = ""
nChar = nChar & "9,13,28,29,30,31,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,"
nChar = nChar & "138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,"
nChar = nChar & "153,154,155,156,157,158,159,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,"
nChar = nChar & "1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,6155,6156,6157,6158,8203,8204,"
nChar = nChar & "8205,8206,8207,8233,8234,8235,8236,8237,8238,8289,8290,8291,8292,"
nChar = nChar & "8298,8299,8300,8301,8302,8303,64976,64977,64978,64979,64980,64981,"
nChar = nChar & "64982,64983,64984,64985,64986,64987,64988,64989,64990,64991,64992,"
nChar = nChar & "64993,64994,64995,64996,64997,64998,64999,65000,65001,65002,65003,"
nChar = nChar & "65004,65005,65006,65007,65060,65061,65062,65063,65064,65065,65066,"
nChar = nChar & "65067,65068,65069,65070,65071,65279"

nArrSearch = Split(nChar, ",")

With Selection

    For N = 0 To UBound(nArrSearch)
        nSearchStr = ChrW(CSng(nArrSearch(N)))
        nSearchStr = "*" & nSearchStr & "*"
        Set C = .Find(nSearchStr, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
            If nRng Is Nothing Then
                Set nRng = C
            Else
                Set nRng = Union(nRng, C)
            End If
            firstAddress = C.Address(0, 0)
            Do While Not C Is Nothing
                Set C = .FindNext(C)
                If C.Address(0, 0) = firstAddress Then Exit Do

                Set nRng = Union(nRng, C)
            Loop
        End If
    Next N
End With
    If Not nRng Is Nothing Then
        nMsg = "Based on Your Selection : " & Selection.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine & _
                "Total Found : " & nRng.Cells.Count & vbNewLine

        If MsgBox(nMsg & vbNewLine & _
                "Do you want to remove invisible character ?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Remove Invisible Character") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

        bRemoved = True
        For N = 0 To UBound(nArrSearch)
            nSearchStr = ChrW(CSng(nArrSearch(N)))
            'MsgBox AscB(nSearchStr)
           ' MsgBox nRng.Replace(Asc(CSng(nArrSearch(N))), "", MatchByte:=True)
            If nRng.Replace(nSearchStr, "", MatchByte:=True) <> True Then
                bRemoved = False
            End If
        Next N

        If bRemoved Then
            MsgBox "Invisible Character Removed", , "Completed"
        Else
            MsgBox "Some invisible character not able to remove" & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please inform the Developer for further improvement", , "Completed"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Based on Your Selection : " & Selection.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine & _
                "No Invisible Character Found", vbInformation

    End If

End Sub
```